# Kendo ui Angular 2

Tags: kendo-ui

How to change the kendo button icon conditionally...

In Angular 2 , I have to change the icon of the kendo button on click for example initially it is having an icon say check after click the icon has to be changed to checked

Comment: I tried using the event of angular 2 and did the dom manipulation is that correct or is there any best way to do it

Comment: Code? We can’t do anything unless we see it

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test it.

```
public isClicked: boolean = false;

onClick(): {
    this.isClicked = true;
}

<button kendoButton type="submit" [primary]="true" (click)="onClick()">{{isClicked ? 'Checked' : 'Check'}}</button>
```

Or to change Font awesome icon:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `

        // FontAwsome icon
        <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <button kendoButton (click)="onClick()" [iconClass]="isSett?'fa fa-key fa-fw': 'fa fa-bus fa-fw'">Button</button>
    `
})
class AppComponent {
public isSett: boolean = true;

  onClick(){
      this.isSett = false;
  }
}
```

Example: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wCTm8LkcB4gfNri06lFC?p=preview)